# Dusupay.com form do not redirect me why

Tags: php, web, e-commerce

```
<form method="post" action="http://sandbox.dusupay.com/dusu_payments/dusupay" target="_blank">
  <input type="hidden" name="dusupay_merchantId" value="1000" required>
  <input type="hidden" name="dusupay_amount" value="5000" optional>
  <input type="hidden" name="dusupay_currency" value="UGX" required>
  <input type="hidden" name="dusupay_itemId" value="Item1" required>
  <input type="hidden" name="dusupay_itemName" value="MyItem" required>
  <input type="hidden" name="dusupay_transactionReference" value="080634" required>
  <input type="hidden" name="dusupay_redirectURL" value="http://sanditsolution.com/" optional>
  <input type="hidden" name="dusupay_successURL" value="https://sandbox.dusupay.com/transactions/check_status/1000/080634.json" optional>
  <!--<input type="hidden" name="dusupay_logo" value="" optional>-->
  <!--<input type="hidden" name="dusupay_hash" value="securityMacKey" required>-->
  <input type="image" name="submit" src="https://www.dusupay.com/img/paybuttons/dusupaybtn6.png" />
</form>
```

Use below page for test,
http://blog.dusupay.com/using-dusupay-test-cards-on-sandbox-account/

code is here,
https://dusupay.com/pages/dusupay_developer

After successful payment why this form is not redirect me my site or (merchant website).

Answer (score 0):

Provided is a **Complete order** button to the customer at the end of the transaction.

Customers need to view the last transaction messages 
given that sometimes they include coupons,vouchers, New Account details, etc That the customer needs to view first.

NB:
For the **Pop-Up widget**, don't forget to add parameters below as-well;

```
dusupay_redirectURL=""

dusupay_successURL=""
```

This will avail the redirection button at the end of the transaction.

Thanks.